# ASP.NET with Javascript disabled

Tags: asp.net, javascript

As you probably know, ASP.NET injects some javascript code to the form, like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var theForm = document.forms['aspnetForm'];
if (!theForm) {
    theForm = document.aspnetForm;
}
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
    if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
        theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
        theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
        theForm.submit();
    }
}
//]]>
</script>
```

Now, the problem with this is that if I turn Javascript off (using WebDev toolbar in FF), I get

"Browser does not support script" at the top of the page.

Does anyone know how I can set this  tag, for this bit of auto-injected js?

Thanks
Duncan

Comment: This is one of the many things about ASP.NET that has always aggravated me.  Why can't it degrade with at least basic levels of grace?

Comment: ASP.NET degrades very nice, f.e. with validation stuff, updatepanels, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

This is **not** a notification from asp.net. Are you sure there are no `<noscript>` blocks on your website?

Perhaps you are using some third party menu component?

Comment: I have other <script> elements which I add a <noscript> to (and keep blank).  If I view the source, then there is a <noscript> block after the script I outlined above, but it has the default "Browser does not support script" put there by the browser.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the affected webpage?

Comment: Thanks Jan, but it's in production at the moment so I can't!  However if I view source, then I can see the above <script> block which has been put there by ASP.NET.  Below this is the default <noscript> which has been added by the browser, because I can't set my own.

Comment: The noscript is not added by ASP.NET, just remove every other javascript part until it doesn't show up :-)